# How to group data from a model with repeating names Python Odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-15

My Odoo model has repeating values.
How to group data from a model with repeating names.
I need to get a data format like this

```
Administrator : name Administrator age 33  
                name Administrator age 43
                name Administrator age 32
Sam: name Sam age 31
     name Sam age 22
     name Sam age 32
     name Sam age 12
Anastatia : name Anastasia age 44
            name Anastasia age 55
            ...
```

**.py**

```
class FirstTestModel(models.Model):
    _name = "first.model"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']
    _description = "Test Model"

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True, )
    age = fields.Integer(string='Age', )

    def action_calculate(self):
        search = self.search([])
        for all_values in search:
            string_name_age = "%s : %s" % (all_values.name, str(all_values.age))
            print(string_name_age)
```

**List of users in the database**

[image]

When I go to the user page I have a calculate button. When I click it I get the Python terminal data

**.xml**

```
<record id="first_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">first.model.form</field>
        <field name="model">first.model</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <header>
                    <button id="button_calculate" name="action_calculate" string="Calculate" class="btn-primary" type="object"/>
```

[image]

The point is to get all the same names from the database, sorted by age, and put them into groups. For example, all Administrator names must be a group.

```
 Administrator : name Administrator age 35
             name Administrator age 37
             name Administrator age 56
             name Administrator age 66
Sam : name Sam age 13
      name Sam age 22
      name Sam age 32
      name Sam age 55
      name Sam age 62
```

and so on.

Then I would transfer this data to the page in Odoo
I just started learning Python and odoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code might give a similar output, but why you need it is what makes me curious. Please let us know what you are trying to achieve so we can help better

```
def action_calculate(self):
    search = self.search([])
    string_name_age = ""
    for all_values in search:
        same_name_items = self.search([("name","=",all_values.name)], order="age asc")
        string_name_age += all_values.name + " :"
        for items in same_name_items:
            string_name_age += "name: %s  age %s \n" % (items.name, str(items.age))
    print(string_name_age)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I get the error
AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'search'

Comment: And if I remove the .env I get
Anastasia :name: Anastasia : age: 5 
name: Anastasia : age: 5 
name: Anastasia : age: 5 
name: Anastasia : age: 5 
name: Anastasia : age: 5

Comment: and what you are trying to get I don't think I understand correctly, add the answer of this question in the main question

Comment: I supplemented the question. and also, I sorted by age this way 
x = sorted(search, key=lambda search: search.age)
 print(x)

Comment: Thank you! No errors, but the result shows only one name several times. But I would like to display all names by group from the database.
Anastasia :name: Anastasia  age 5 
name: Anastasia  age 5 
name: Anastasia  age 5 
name: Anastasia  age 5 
name: Anastasia  age 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244688/discussion-between-muhammad-yusuf-and-anton-balmakov).

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code so that there would not be so many requests to the database, through the filtered method.

My code :

```
def action_calculate(self):
    search = self.search([])
    string_name_age = ""
    name_done = []
    for all_values in search:
        if all_values.name not in name_done:
            same_name_items = search.filtered(lambda lm: lm.name == all_values.name).sorted(key=lambda r: r.age)
            string_name_age += all_values.name + " :"
            for items in same_name_items:
                string_name_age += "name: %s  age %s \n" % (items.name, str(items.age))
            name_done.append(all_values.name)

    print(string_name_age)
    self.message_post(body=string_name_age)
```

This is working.